# как добавить возможность выбирать проекты в visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

[image: Visual Studio]

У меня несколько проектов, но нет возможности выбирать их. Сверху справа от Any CPU должна быть кнопка выбора между проектами, но её там нет. Как её добавить?